# Data migration to new drupal website

Tags: entities, nodes

I'm planning to migrate a non-Drupal website to a new one based on Drupal 7. The current website is using object oriented model classes. In addition I use Doctrine for database abstraction and object relational mapper.

I've been reading about Drupal nodes, entities and content types and now I need to decide how to integrate my Doctrine entities in Drupal. Here are some of my thoughts:

- I'd rather keep my Doctrine entities because Doctrine offers a great way to set up relationships between objects.
- I don't mind creating forms manually (html,css,js) for each of my entities. It seems to me that using the drupal hook for altering content type forms is less elegant.
- In the current website the users are Doctrine entities as well. I'm wondering if it would be okay to add a field to the default drupal user and reference my doctrine user id there?

In general, I want to avoid bad design decisions. I understand that not using nodes for the model in Drupal seems strange, but would managing your model separetely from Drupal be considered as a bad practice?